# Having an element on top or bottom of the site depending on the circumstances

Tags: javascript, html, css, media

When working on my first responsive website I encountered the following issue:

For wide pages I would like to have img over all divs. Something like:

```
<img src="image.jpg"/>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
...
```

But when we shrink browser I would like to have it under all of my divs:

```
...
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<img src="image.jpg"/>
```

The only solution I found for it is to have

```
<img id="img_1" src="image.jpg"/>
<div> some content </div>
<div> some content </div>
<img id="img_2" src="image.jpg"/>
```

and in media queries "switch on" and "switch off" the img I need or not at the moment. But it seems to me, to be not very elegant and well seen solution... I was thinking about using position: absolute but it generates more ond more issuses for me.

Thank you very much for any help! 
Grzegorz

Comment: I'd say your sulotion is the best. You can use display: flex, and then alter the order of the images, but then you will end up with more code than two img elements. The browser will cache the image aswell, so the user wont have to download it two times.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will work to you:

```
<img src="image.jpg" id="yourImg"/>


function moveElement(Elm_Id, top, left) {
    $("#" + Elm_Id).css({ "position": "relative", "top": top, "left": left });
}
```

Must be called like:

```
moveElement("yourImg", "200px", "300px");
```

Check [here](http://www.learnfast.ninja/posts/53a983c20edf641c15af77a8) for more info.